# Line numbering in Grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have command in Grep:

```
cat nastava.html | grep  '<td>[A-Z a-z]*</td><td>[0-9/]*</td>'  | sed 's/[ \t]*<td>\([A-Z a-z]*\)<\/td><td>\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)\/[0-9]\{2\}\([0-9]\{2\}\)<\/td>.*/\1 mi\3\2 /' 
|sort|grep -n ".*" | sed -r 's/(.*):(.*)/\1. \2/' >studenti.txt
```

I don't understand second line, sort is ok, grep -n means to num that sorted list, but why do we use here ".*"? It won't work without it, and i don't understand why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `grep` is used purely for the side effect of the line numbering with the `-n` option here, so the main thing is really to use a regular expression which matches all the input lines.  As such, `.*` is not very elegant -- `^` would work without scanning every line, and `$` trivially matches every line as well.  Since you know the input lines are not empty, thus contain at least one character, the simple regular expression `.` would work perfectly, too.

However, as the end goal is to perform line numbering, a better solution is to use a dedicated tool for this purpose.

```
... | sort | nl -ba -s '. '
```

The `-ba` option specifies to number all lines (the default is to only add a line number to non-empty lines; we know there are no empty lines, so it's not strictly necessary here, but it's good to know) and the `-s` option specifies the separator string to put after the number.

A possible minor complication is that the line number format is whitespace-padded, so in the end, this solution may not work for you if you specifically want unpadded numbers.  (But a `sed` postprocessor to fix that up is a lot simpler than the postprocessor for `grep` you have now -- just `sed 's/^ *//'` will remove leading whitespace).

... As an aside, the ugly `cat | grep | sed` pipeline can be abbreviated to just

```
sed -n 's%[ \t]*<td>\([A-Z a-z]*\)</td><td>\([0-9]\{1,3\}\)/[0-9]\{2\}\([0-9]\{2\}\)</td>.*%\1 mi\3\2 %p' nastava.html
```

The `cat` was never necessary in the first place, and the `sed` script can easily be refactored to only print when a substitution was performed (your `grep` regular expression was not exactly equivalent to the one you have in the `sed` script but I assume that was the intent).  Also, using a different separator avoids having to backslash the slashes.

... And of course, if `nastava.html` is your own web page, the whole process is umop apisdn.  You should have the students results in a machine-readable form, and generate a web page from that, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Nice,the `nl` filter! Previously I always used `cat -n` for this.

Answer (score 3):

`grep` needs a regular expression to match. You can't run `grep` with no expression at all. If you want to number all the lines, just specify an expression that matches anything. I'd probably use `^` instead of `.*`.